# why not use boost::optional as a better scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

why isn't it common place to use boost::optional as a scoped_ptr, it seems like it is better as the object is created on the stack instead of the heap. But I have never seen it used this way. My question is, what are the disadvantages of using a boost::optional as a kind of scoped_ptr other than the obvious inability to do polymorphism?

Comment: What's wrong with just declaring the variable you want, why wrap it in boost::optional?

Comment: I had the same thoughts. From a performance point of view boost::optional would beat scoped_ptr. Only serious drawback is the semantics (or lack of polymorphism as 'milleniumbug' points out)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that polymorphism **is** the point of `scoped_ptr`. Otherwise you would just declare the variable locally, on stack.

```
int main()
{
    Class object(52, 25); //sample declaration, with constructor arguments passed
}
```

EDIT 1 (response to additional info from comments):

`boost::scoped_ptr` is actually rarely used for the purpose you describe (mainly because you can't copy nor move `boost::scoped_ptr`, making the class you store it in uncopyable and unmoveable). It seems that `boost::optional` is appropriate for that purpose, but...

Note that there is little point in local use of `boost::optional` (that is, not returned from a function), since you can create objects on stack at your will:

```
void another_function()
{
    if(some_condition())
    {
        Class object(0, 0); // create the object
        // use the object
    }
    else
    {
        // don't use the object
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another purpose which is to have a member that can be created and destroyed independently of the class that it is a member of. Maybe a lazy initialised object?

Answer (score 2):

For one, I'd say semantics.

I would need to refresh my memory on `boost::optional` and `boost::scoped_ptr` details to give an opinion on the technical aspect, but when it comes to maintainability, using `optional`s in place of pointers is bound to confuse people who read your code.

Comment: It would help if boost / std would define something like e.g. value_ptr with the same implementation as boost::optional.